Automating interaction with excel files using graph API
I need to be able to have some apps read/write data in excel workbooks without user interaction. For context, the use case here is an app that automates updating firewall rules across multiple platforms based on data stored in a spreadsheet maintained by a network team. I am running into an issue with the graph API in that I cant access excel data with an app-only token.
I have implemented app-only token auth, but when calling /me/drive/root/children or /me/drive/items/{drive-item-id}/workbook/worksheets('someSheet')/usedRange, or any endpoint I can find to interact with an excel workbook, I am getting "/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow."
What is the best way to do this? Is there a set of permissions that I can add to grant access to an excel workbook via an app-only token?
If not, what is there any way to implement delegated authentication flow without user interaction?

Workbook API doesn't support application permissions, so you can't interact with excel files without signed-in user.
Sometimes admin can create some service account and disable MFA for this account. Then your app can sign-in with that service account with delegated permissions and interact with excel files.

Thanks @user2250152.  Do you happen to have a link to a doc that covers the service account option? Working with this in an environment I have full admin access to.
